# How do i add amount to the paypal form

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I would like to insert an `Amount` to `PayPal form` from my website and when they click the `Submit` button.

The `item_name`, `quantity` both are the display on the PayPal website, but `Price per item` is empty? I need to add `Price per item` whatever amount is in the `amount field`?

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="upload">
<input type="hidden" value="xxx@gmail.com" name="business">
<input type="hidden" value="T-SHIRT" name="item_name">
<input type="hidden" value="6.99" name="amount_1">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="custom">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" value="http://localhost/paypalform/my_ipn.php" name="notify_url">
<input type="hidden" 
value="http://localhost/paypalform/checkout_complete.php" 
name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
<input type="hidden" value="Return to The Store" name="cbt">
<input type="hidden" 
value="http://localhost/paypalform/paypal_cancel.php" 
name="cancel_return">
<input type="hidden" value="GB" name="lc">
<input type="hidden" value="EUR" name="currency_code">
<input type="image" name="submit" 
src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif">

</form>
```

**Paypal Screenshot**

[image]

I have Try amount instead of amount_1 PayPal showing error message

```
Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `amount` instead of `amount_1`

```
<input type="hidden" value="6.99" name="amount">
```

Comment: i have tried it but now it is showing this message `Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.`

Comment: Can you take at logs and check if any error is there.